# Is it possible to automatically call an internal exception method when the exception is thrown?

Tags: java, exception, reporting

I need to execute a method every time a certain custom exception is thrown. The executed code will report the exception to my API. The exception class has a `boolean` parameter that states if the exception should be reported or not. Let's assume I have the following exception coded:

```java
public MyException extends Exception {
    
    private final String message;

    private final int code;

    private final boolean report;
 
    public MyException(String message, int code, boolean report) {
        this.message = message;
        this.code = code;
        this.report = report;
    }

    public void report() {
        if(report) {
            // Report some stuff
        }
    }

}
```

When `MyException` is thrown I want the code in `report()` to be executed. I have already thought of calling the method manually:

```java
try {
     throw new MyException("Test", 1, true);
} catch(MyException e) {
     e.report();
}
```

But I was wondering if It was possible to call the function automatically on an exception throw.

```java
...
throw new MyExcepion("Test", 1, true); // Implicitlly calls report()
...
```

Note that I do not want to call it on exception instantiation because something like this could happen:

```java
...
public MyException(String message, int code, boolean report) {
        this.message = message;
        this.code = code;
        this.report = report;
        report();
}
...
```

```java
int var = 0;
MyException ex = new MyException("test", 1, true);
if (var != 0) {
    throw ex;
}
//  Here the exception would be reported but never thrown.
```

Is this even possible? Can 3rd party library do this? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Spring AspectJ might be answer if already have spring - see example https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-aop/aspectj-afterthrowing-annotation-example/

Comment: Seems to be what I am looking for but I would first want to know if there is a native way of doing it without libraries as Spring is a pretty heavy library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use and [UncaughtExceptionHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html).

The usage pattern would be:

1. Create your own `UncaughtExceptionHandler`, which is just an implementation of one method: `uncaughtException()`
2. Register your handler on each Thread or ThreadGroup using [setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler))

If you are using any framework, such as Java EE or Spring, there might be better (cleaner) methods, such as Java EE [ExceptionMapper](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html).

Comment: This would only work if the exception is not caught right? So I would still need to call the `report()` method if a catch it.